# Is there a way to clear a non-rectangular area in a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Using javascript, I've drawn several polygon images on my canvas.

I'd like to, based on user events/clicks, be able to clear a section of the canvas (one of those polygon images), which is an irregular shape, not a rectangle.

So, I cannot use clearRect() for my purpose.

Can anyone think of a way I can do that?

Essentially, I'd like to make a portion of my canvas transparent, but it is not a rectangular shape...  Once I have an area defined with which I can fill() and stroke(), can I not also clear() it...  I know that such a function is not available.  What are folks doing to clear **irregularly shaped** sections?

I'm a little new to this, so apologies in advance if this sounds like a silly question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ctx.clip()` to define the current stroke as a clipping region.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing

I also created a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/6ABp7/

The clipping path is part of the graphics state, so you can `.save()` the previous state, set clipping, draw some more stuff, and then `.restore()` the original state.

Comment: Alnitak, that's interesting.  I had actually run into that tutorial while I was reading before posting here and had already tested the following, which didn't work: ctx.clip(); ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.width,ctx.height);.  You see, I assumed that if I clip first, then only that region will be cleared (not the whole rectangle), but nothing actually happened when I did the above (and furthermore, I don't know how to unclip my region after that). What did you have in mind?  I'm assuming it's not what I was trying.  How would I use clip to CLEAR my region...

Comment: @Boriana see updated answer.  Yours probably didn't work because you used `ctx.width` instead of `canvasElement.width`

Comment: You were right!  It's working perfectly now :-).  I was indeed using the wrong width and height in clearRect().  I should have seen that right away.  Thank you for the thorough answer and the great demo.